# How to use Choicesjs ajax?

Tags: javascript

I am using Choicesjs:

In their documentation they say that in order to pre-fill the input with values, we have to use their ajax function:

https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices#ajaxfn

```
var example = new Choices(element);

example.ajax(function(callback) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        callback(data, 'value', 'label');
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

But i dont understand, in this line: `response.json().then(function(data)``

How should the data be? In my database the genres, which is the data in this case, is just an array of srings like: `['rock','pop','rap']`

But the callback say: `callback(data, 'value', 'label');`

how im i supposed to use this callback?

Should my genres instead of being an array should be an object with a key value, a key label, and then data, would be that object?

UPDATE

I have tried changing the callback to be an array of objects.. but now d
oesnt throw an error.. but it also does not populate the field with the data...

code:

```
  await genresMultiOptions.ajax(function(callback) {
    fetch(`/api/users/${loggedInUser.username.slug}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          const d = data.genres.map(x => ({'value': x, 'label': x}))
          console.log(d)
          callback(d, 'value', 'label');
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

Any idea.. on how to get this working, i mean , pre populate the filed with data from the backend?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to expect your data to comeback as an array of objects. If all you return is an array of strings, you might want to transform the data before calling callback: `data = data.map(x => ({'key': x}))` and then use the same key for both the value and the label: `callback(data, 'key', 'key')`.

Comment: I tried your idea, but i get an error: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` .. i have updated the post.. any ideas what could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem which was setting the values of the input with the values from the db...

Instead of using their ajax helper.. which was confusing and did not work for me... i used the `setValue` method on the choices obj:

```
async function getUserData() {
  let loggedInUser
  try {
    await axios
      .get(`/api/user_data`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data) {
          loggedInUser = res.data
          return
        }
        // tell them nothing came back
        console.error('no users on the res to make ajax and populate choicesjs')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('no users found', err);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  genresMultiOptions.setValue(loggedInUser.username.genres);
}
getUserData()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should my genres instead of being an array should be an object with a key value, a key label, and then data, would be that object?

Seems like yes. In the example further up where it shows how to statically define choices it has that structure:

```
const example = new Choices(element, {
 choices: [
   {value: 'One', label: 'Label One'},
   {value: 'Two', label: 'Label Two', disabled: true},
   {value: 'Three', label: 'Label Three'},
  ],
 });
```

Seems to me the string arguments provide the keys to each of these fields

Comment: I tried faking the data to be an object with that structure like: `response.json().then(function(data) {
          debugger
          data.genres = { value: 'val', label: 'lab'}
          callback(data.genres, 'data.genres.value', 'data.genres.label');
        });` but i got an error:  `Cannot read property 'genres' of undefined`